# ngx formly custom repeat section not repeating value by default angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, ngx-formly

I am using [ngx-formly](https://formly.dev/guide/properties-options) library to create dynamic forms. So from [this link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-key-val-pairs-9xqshq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdata.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts), I am trying repeat custom component.

Here is the custom component

import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { FieldArrayType } from "@ngx-formly/core";

```
@Component({
  selector: "formly-repeat-section",
  templateUrl: "./formly-repeat-section.component.html"
})
export class FormlyRepeatSectionComponent extends FieldArrayType { }
```

html for this compnent

```
<div *ngFor="let field of field.fieldGroup; let i = index;" class="row">
  <formly-field class="col" [field]="field"></formly-field>
  <div class="col-sm-2 d-flex align-items-center">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" (click)="remove(i)">Remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="margin:30px 0;">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" (click)="add()">This Add works</button>
</div>
```

entry in app module

```
   FormlyModule.forRoot({
        wrappers: [
            { name: "panel", component: PanelWrapperComponent },
        ],
        types: [
            {
                name: "chips", wrappers: ["form-field"], component: FormlyChipsComponent,
                defaultOptions: { defaultValue: [], },
            },
            { name: "repeat", component: FormlyRepeatSectionComponent },
            { name: "button", component: FormlyButtonComponent },
        ],
    }),
```

and the config object

```
{
            key: "num_format_info",
            type: "repeat",
            templateOptions: {
              addText: "Add New",
            },
            className: "btn yo",
            fieldArray: {
              fieldGroupClassName: "group0-class-name",
              fieldGroup: [
                {
                  className: "col-sm-4 myclass", type: "chips", key: "num_format_info1", templateOptions: {
                    label: "num_format_info1", required: true,
                  },
                }
              ],
            },
          },
```

on load it does not show the field, by by clicking on `This add works`, it adds a new row. In the stackblitz i tried the same, and it works.

What can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

you will add your component name to imports and declaration in your module.

Example:

```
  declarations: [
    FormlyRepeatSectionComponent
  ]
  imports: [
    FormlyRepeatSectionComponent
  ]
```